# Do RES and USED of a process include the cache and buffer of the process?

Tags: top, virtual-memory

In the output of `top`, I heard that RES of a process is the part of RAM occupied by the process, and includes the process' code, data, and shared libraries which are in RAM.

I wonder if RES of a process includes or excludes the cache and buffer of the process?

Similar question for USED of a process, i.e. does USED of a process include or exclude the cache and buffer of the process?

I have this question because in the output of `free`, there are items for cache and buffer, which are both counted and excluded from used, although not for a single process but for all the processes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filecache and all buffers are not in any way associated to a process. If 2 processes access a file, which causes it to be in the cache, the kernel does not remember who accessed the file.

Take a look at `/proc/meminfo` and its [explanation](https://superuser.com/a/521552/150695).

To see what a process occupied memory consists of, you can see the files `maps` and `smaps` in `/proc/PID` directories for each process. There you will find which libraries are part of it and also mmapped files, but those do not occupy any memory, they are just mapped into a process' memory space.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The process RES includes the `cached` at least in my case when the cached is used for mmapped files:

```
top - 05:07:51 up 7 days,  6:37,  1 user,  load average: 0.37, 0.28, 0.22
Tasks: 219 total,   1 running, 125 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  64463540k total, 63729264k used,   734276k free,    97804k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free, 14275740k cached
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 4772 druid     20   0 96.8g  57g  11g S  0.0 93.9 254:51.01 java
```

You can see that 57g+14275740k cached will be exceeding the 64463540k total if they are mutually exclusive.

You can verify that by looking at /proc/PID/status, RssFile should be the total mmapped file size.

Unfortunately, the only answer under the only question I can find on this topic on the internet can't explain what I am seeing on my system, took me quite some time to figure that out, hopefully I can help more people here.

Comment: @Marki555 : Any comment hear? confused about which is the right answer here.